# PHP Drop down menu from two mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with first name and surname which I can populate a drop down list with either. but I want one drop down with both. Which I have also managed to do . But I am stuck on then when I submit this information that both items (first and surname) are then sent back in to my database again.

This is what I have so far

```
<table align="center">
<form name="addreport" action="addreport.php" method="post">
<?php
$options = '';
$filter=mysql_query("select * from students");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
    $options .="<option value = '".$row['firstname']."'>" . $row['firstname'] . " " .$row['surname']."'>" . $row['surname'] . "</option>";
}


$menu="<name='filter'>
      <select name='names'>
      " . $options . "
    </select></td>";
?>
<tr><td><font color='white' size='6px'>Student Name:<?php echo $menu; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><font color='white' size='6px'>Teacher Name:<input type="text" name="location" size="12"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><font color='white' size='6px'>Report:</td>
<tr><td><textarea name="report" style="font-size:15px;width:800px;height:300px;"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><font color='white' size='6px'>Intervention:</td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea name="interv" style="font-size:15px;width:800px;height:300px;"></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
<table align="center">
<tr><td><center><input type="submit" class="btn2" value="Add"></center></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The stick is sending the info on in my form back to my database. As you can see I can send one back but not both. Please can someone help me structure this last part.

Comment: Firstly, instead of processing in PHP, you can change your query to: `select id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname) from students`. And `"<option>"` should be `"<option value=$row['id']>"`. You need to send selected ID when form is submitted.

Comment: `$options` is never echoed. Your question is quite not clear, especially about your concrete programming question. You write a lot what you already do, but very little what your problem is, how you tried to solve it and why that solution didn't work for you.

Comment: @hakre options is echoed because it's concatenated with $menu.

Comment: Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: @PaulM you need to set the "value" attribute of each option to just the first name, then it will only re-submit the first name, if that's what you want. using an ID for each student rather than their name would be more robust though, otherwise you could run into duplicates. And yeah as axiac says your database code is out of date and has security vulnerabilities, you should stop using it immediately and switch to a supported system. Once you change to PHP7 (as eventually you will have to) you'll find it doesn't exist anyway.

Comment: use value attribute  in option "<option value='fistname-lastname'>" it will send

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

I have two columns in one table called students "Firstname and Surname"

From this in a new html page I want a drop down selection with both firstname and surname IE 

Student Name : Joe Swanson
                          Peter Griffin
                          Lois Griffin

I can populate this dropdown fine, however when I submit I want both firsname and surname to post from my form back in to another table along with other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you should not use `mysql` driver. Either use `mysqli` or `PDO` driver . Now as I came to understand your problem, you want to show complete name in drop down but want to update only first name . Then you can use `value` property of `select` tag like this :-

```
$filter=mysql_query("select * from students");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) 
{
    $options .="<option value = '".$row['firstname'].",".$row['surname']."'>" . $row['firstname'] . " " .$row['surname'] . "</option>";
}

// rest of the code
```

Now try to understand the code . Your drop down will look like this :-

Data :-

```
First Name          |      Sur Name
----------------------------------------

Deepak                     Dixit
Coder                      Developer
```

HTML

```
<select name="names">
<option value = "Deepak,Dixit"> Deepak Dixit </option>
<option value = "Coder,Developer"> Coder Developer </option>
</select>
```

At PHP side you need to explode the select value with a comma (,) (Its your choice) only like this:-

```
<?php

$first_name = explode(",", $_POST['names'])[0];
$sur_name = explode(",", $_POST['names'])[1];
```

Comment: Hi Deepak. understand my code is somewhat old but the problem is I only use this every now and then plus my code never sees the outside world only inside the corporate environment. Plus its only ever a few pages at a time. I will give this a run though and see how I get on. I will endeavour try to use new versions once I have completed this. P

Comment: @PaulM Sorry but I am unable to get your problem . Either edit your question and ask it clearly or mention that in comment. Thanks

Comment: Table> Student Names
has columns for Firstname and Surname 
this populates my dynamic dropdown which is the code above.
In my drop down I can view both Firstname and Surname fine.
However on submit only one value gets written to my next table.
I want to write both firstname and surname back to my next table >reports table > Firstname and surname.

Comment: @PaulM, then you can create an hidden field and catch both first name and surname from these two fields . Can you show your form related code .

Comment: @PaulM "my code never sees the outside world only inside the corporate environment". And you would trust everyone in the corporate environment not to attack the system, or not to accidentally download some malicious virus/code which tries? You should never use obscurity as your security. You can't assume that anything coming into your application from _anywhere_ is safe. That road leads to eventual disaster. If you have the time, upgrade your code. Changing to mysqli in particular is not that hard and there are plenty of examples online.